# Delete vs. Edit etiquette

Tags: discussion, editing, answers

If an error is found in my answer, is it appropriate to delete the answer and let someone else more knowledgeable answer?

Or is should I attempt to correct my solution through edits?

What is the general etiquette?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Is sometimes keeping wrong answer reasonable?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159/is-sometimes-keeping-wrong-answer-reasonable)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's up to you, but I would lean towards editing or, if you can't fix the error, striking out the incorrect parts and leaving it up as a lesson to others. There are situations where multiple people give the same incorrect answer to a question because they all made the same mistake, and having at least one example of that mistake available is valuable!

Comment: I should add that if you feel bad for any reputation you may gain from the mistake you can mark it as CW.

Comment: Sometimes I have edited the answer, saying that it is wrong and why at the top, but leaving the answer anyway so that others can see what was wrong.